# MSAccess - Export Fixed Length Text Records

Tags: ms-access

I need to produce a fixed length record from an Access table.

Details:

1. The Fields are all defined TEXT, each with the full width specified
2. Null data needs to be presented at full width (padded w/spaces)
3. Export needs a SPACE between each field

I get close using Access' export wizard:

Simplified Data Table for example - w/(Length Spec)

```
A1(15)      A2(10)  A3(10)  A4(10)  A5(8)
000123456   111                     AAA
000234567           222             BBB
000345678                   333     CCC
```

Export_1:  Export>Text>Delimited>Advanced>Delimiter={space}>TextQual = {none}, I get the following incorrect result.

`A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
000123456 111   AAA
000234567  222  BBB
000345678   333 CCC`

Looks to be trimming the data values, and then inserting the {space} delimiter.  Note:  Exporting as Fixed Width produces a similar result.

**Question:**

1. Is there a way to export and preserve the Specified field width (i.e., w/spaces), as well as insert a {space} between fields?
2. I suppose I could step thru each record in VBA, pad, then trim the attrs, then write out the line to a TXT file.  I guess I am looking for a less brute force approach...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the TransferText method:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportFixed , , "YourTableOrQueryName", "d:\folder\filename.txt", False
```

Comment: Thank you Gustav,almost there,  That method produces the fixed width record with {space} padding.  I just need to add one more {space} between attributes.  Guessing an ExportSpec will accomodate (?)

Comment: Maybe. Or you could just include in your query some fields named _Space1_, _Space2_, etc.: `Space3: Space(1)`.

Comment: Hehe, cheating, but a great idea. :)